# Python Program to create Container if not exist with partition key and unique Key

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I want to write python script to create container only if it not exist with partition key and unique key.

```
Steps for  Creating Alert Container
 1. Create Container With Container ID: alerts
 2. Add Partition Key as /user_tenant
 3. Add Unique Key as /alert_id
```

reference link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-python#create-a-container

plz suggest the api that will create container if it not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gaurav Mantri
Below is the working code as suggested by you.
for **uniqueKeys** we need to add it inside **uniqueKeyPolicy** as shown in below code.

```
import azure.cosmos.documents as documents
from azure.cosmos import cosmos_client, http_constants, errors
import os

url = os.environ['COSMOS_DB_END_POINT']
key = os.environ['COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY']
database_name = os.environ["COSMOS_DB_DATABASE_ID"]
client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(url, {'masterKey': key})

container_definition = {'id': 'alerts_test',
                        'partitionKey':
                            {
                                'paths': ['/user_tenant'],
                                'kind': documents.PartitionKind.Hash
                            },
                        'uniqueKeyPolicy': {
                            'uniqueKeys':
                                [
                                    {'paths': ['/alert_id']}
                                ]
                        }
                        }

try:
    container = client.CreateContainer("dbs/" + database_name, container_definition, {'offerThroughput': 400})
    print("New Container Created:")
    print(container)
except errors.HTTPFailure as e:
    if e.status_code == http_constants.StatusCodes.CONFLICT:
        container = client.ReadContainer("dbs/" + database_name + "/colls/" + container_definition['id'])
        print(container)
    else:
        raise e
```

Comment: Perfect! I have deleted my answer because you have provided the correct solution.

Comment: From what I can tell errors does not have a method called HTTPFailure, it just has the following?

 'CosmosAccessConditionFailedError',
 'CosmosClientTimeoutError',
 'CosmosHttpResponseError',
 'CosmosResourceExistsError',
 'CosmosResourceNotFoundError',
 'HttpResponseError',
 'ResourceExistsError',
 'ResourceNotFoundError'

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

**Create Connection**

```
import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client

COMOS_MASTER_KEY = "*****" 
COMOS_ENDPOINT = "https://account.documents.azure.com:port/" 

client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(url=COMOS_ENDPOINT, credential={"masterKey":COMOS_MASTER_KEY})
```

**Create Database If Not Exist**

```
database = client.create_database_if_not_exists({'id': database_name,'offer_throughput':20000})
```

**Create Collection If it does Not Exist**

```
database.create_container_if_not_exists(id="collection_name",partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/partition_key_path"),offer_throughput=1000)
```

Comment: how can i create container using multiple container? is it possible?